# What's the efficient way to filter a python dictionary based on whether an element in a value list exists?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a dictionary (table) defined like this:

```
table = {"id": [1, 2, 3]}, {"file": ['good1.txt', 'bad2.txt', 'good3.txt']}
```

and I have a list of bad candidates that should be removed:

```
to_exclude = ['bad0.txt', 'bad1.txt', 'bad2.txt']
```

I hope to filter the table based on if the file in a row of my table can be found inside to_exclude.

```
filtered = {"id": [1, 2]}, {"file": ['good1.txt', 'good3.txt']}
```

I guess I could use a for loop to check the entries one by one, but I was wondering what's the most python-efficient manner to solve this problem.

Could someone provide some guidance on this? Thanks.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misread the question.  And it was wrong.  Will redo.

Comment: Your data structure is invalid.  Do you mean it to be a list of dictionaries or a single dictionary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you miswrote your data structure.  You have a set of two dictionaries, which is impossible.  (Dictionaries are not hashable).  I'm hoping your actual data is:

```
data = {"id": [1, 2, 3], "file": [.......]}
```

a dictionary with two keys.

So for me, the simplest would be:

```
# Create a set for faster testing
to_exclude_set = set(to_exclude)
# Create (id, file) pairs for the pairs we want to keep
pairs = [(id, file) for id, file in zip(data["id"], data["file"])
          if file not in to_exclude_set]
# Recreate the data structure
result = { 'id': [_ for id, _ in pairs],
           'file': [_ for _, file in pairs] }
```

Comment: Thanks. It works.  I also fixed the original question.